# trabajar con responsive. en local se ve de una forma y en cell de otra

Tags: css3, webservice, web, webview

Buenos amigo tengo una indeligencia diagramando con CSS.
Que pasa...

tengo dos archivos css uno para el responsive y otro para el normal
algo asi.

style-index.css: para el archivo de laptop 
y r-style-index: para el cell

tengo este código.

```css
button.inisesion{
        border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        position: absolute;
        top:3px;
        right:40px;
        padding: 10px 10px ;
        font-family: avan;
        font-size: 12px;
        color:white;
        background-color: red;
        border: none;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        cursor:pointer;
        }
```

es un botón y me funciona perfecto en la configuracion de laptop pero cuando la paso a el responsive el botón cambia los espacio no se ve igual. Esto solo pasa cuando lo subo a github y lo veo mi cell pero si lo veo en la pagina y la achico no pasa nada se ve bien.
les pongo unas foto del problema

[image: imagen del cell]

esto como se ve normal en la computadora.

[image: en la laptop]

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar también el html que esté usando?

Comment: el problema es esta linea  font-size: 12px; deberias usar unidades no pixeles ya que para cada dispositivo un px es diferente...

Answer (score 0):

Pueder verificar el `line-height` para ver si coincide el mismo en ambos casos, sino, ajústalo. Hay opciones para centrar verticalmente los elementos, dependiendo de qué compatibilidad necesitas, pero creo que podrías trabajar algo con *flexbox*.

> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: no me funciono :( 

a.cerrar{
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
   position: absolute;
   top:3px;
   font-family: avan;
   font-weight: 600;
   right:3px;
   background-color: rosybrown;
   padding:7px 10px;
   font-size: 20px;
   text-decoration: none;
   line-height: 1;
   color:#fff;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
    align-items:center;

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes el html?

Answer (score 0):

ya resolvi el problema. tenia que cambiar la tupe a ariel en el código 
button.inisesion{
        border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        position: absolute;
        top:3px;
        right:40px;
        padding: 10px 10px ;
       **quitar esto**  *font-family: avan;*
        **poner esto** font-family: arial;
        font-size: 12px;
        color:white;
        background-color: red;
        border: none;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        cursor:pointer;
        }